# SED remove white space between characters

Tags: unix, sed

I have an xml file whose lines should look like this:

```
<item id=""><myname>FIRST NAME</myname><myurl>http://etc.com</myurl></item>
```

I can easily replace the `" myurl="` below to make the line look like the one above.

```
<item id=""><myname>FIRST NAME" myURL="http://etc.com</myurl></item>
```

Unfortunately, most of them look like this, with different amounts of white space in b/t:

```
<item id=""><myname>FIRST NAME"                   
         myURL="http://etc.com</myurl></item>
```

I can't seem to get a working SED replace for whitespace in b/t characters

Comment: Your XML is malformed in <myURL> - is this intentional?

Comment: Does the last one have a newline or is it wrapped due to a large number of spaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed '/myname>.*\"\s*$/N;s|\"\s*\n*\s*myURL=\"|</myname><myurl>|' file.xml
```

This first tests if the line is incomplete. If it is, it places the next line into the pattern space. In either case, it replaces the original text with the desired text.

BTW, if anyone can tell me a way to match a newline in the pattern space in a character set I would appreciate it. For example, `[\s\n]*` instead of `\s*\n*\s*` in the above expression.

input:

```
<item id=""><myname>FIRST NAME" myURL="http://etc.com</myurl></item>
<item id=""><myname>FIRST NAME"                   
         myURL="http://etc.com</myurl></item>
<item id=""><myname>FIRST NAME" myURL="http://etc.com</myurl></item>
```

output:

```
<item id=""><myname>FIRST NAME</myname><myurl>http://etc.com</myurl></item>
<item id=""><myname>FIRST NAME</myname><myurl>http://etc.com</myurl></item>
<item id=""><myname>FIRST NAME</myname><myurl>http://etc.com</myurl></item>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is regex `'s/   */ /g'` what you're looking for?

For all strings of two or more spaces, this substitutes a single space.

Comment: That's three spaces between the first slash and the asterisk (it's not easy to see).

Comment: `'s/  +/ /g'` (two spaces between the first slash and the plus sign - the code highlighting on this site seems to work differently for question/answer posts and comments...) should do the same. While `*` indicates that the preceding character can occur any number of times (including zero), `+` means "one or more".

Comment: I also like to use `'s/[ \t]+/ /g'` sometimes, which actually replaces any number of reoccurring spaces or tabs with one single space character. Careful though: While `sed -r` does usually support `\t`, you need to explicitly use **Perl regex** for `grep` by declaring `-P`.